# Remove all traces of LUKS from second hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-encryption, luks

I have a new install of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop that I am running headless. I'm using xRDP or SSH to administer it. This system will serve as a backup to my synology.

I've installed a 500GB HDD in it and initially started with full disk encryption for just this data drive. At one point I felt I should not pursue it any longer so I backed out.

Now I am trying to simply create a primary partition on it and format it as 'ext4' but I keep running into issues. I've tried Disk Utility, GParted and `fdisk`, and using all of them when I try to format the drive I get an error saying that the disk is already in use. I've done `lsof` and couldn't find any references to `/dev/sda`.

I've scoured several forums but none had the answer.

When I do `lsblk` I still see a lingering LUKS there, which I do not see in GParted, `fdisk` or Disk Utility. Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME                                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1                                        8:1    0 465.8G  0 part   
  └─luks-c804d3bb-7389-4c43-ab30-5d8b34041044 252:0  0 465.8G  0 crypt 
sdb                                           8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                                        8:17   0 141.3G  0 part  /
└─sdb5                                        8:21   0   7.7G  0 part  [SWAP]
```

And when I try to create 'ext4' over `/dev/sda1`:

```
pankaj@pankaj-desktop:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

How can I do a clean install of this second HDD with an 'ext4' partition and no encryption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to wipe your disk is

```
sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sda
```

and then reboot.  If you want a new partition afterwards, you can create one in [GParted](http://gparted.org/), `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` for the GPT partition table, or `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` for the MS-DOS partition table.

---

The proper way to remove just LUKS while it is in use is to close the dm device like so:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksClose luks-c804d3bb-7389-4c43-ab30-5d8b34041044
```

Make sure to remove the same device from `/etc/crypttab`.

Now, you can write an ext4 filesystem over `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your second suggestion and was able to close out LUKS. Now I am able to format the drive and mount it. I tried up voting but since I have < 15 reputation on SU it did not get publicly displayed.